# error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'RatNum' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Tags: c++, overloading

I'm having an issue with overloading the << operator. I tried to find an answer already but it seemed that most people just hadn't implemented an override. I'm just learning C++ but I believe it may be a scope issue. I am trying to print out a Rational Number (fractions and integers) class, which has two members for the numerator and denominator.

Header file:

```
#ifndef RATMATH_H
#define RATMATH_H

using namespace std;

class RatMath
{

public:
    RatMath(void);

    virtual ~RatMath();

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &output, RatNum &resultObj);

};
#endif
```

in the RatMath class:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream &output, RatNum &resultNum)
{
    int topNum = resultNum.getTopNum();
    int botNum = resultNum.getBotNum();

    output << topNum << "/" << botNum;
    return output;
}
```

and then to call it from int main(), in a GUI class (which isn't declared in the header-not sure if that is an issue but it was working alright before):

```
RatNum testObj = RatNum(1, 3);
cout << testObj;
```

I tried putting the override right in the GUI class to see if it was a scope issue, but then I don't know where to put the 'friend' declaration since the GUI class isn't defined in the header. either way, it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: What does `in the RatMath class:` mean exactly?

Comment: Make the member function static

Comment: @NeilKirk just meaning that the overload implementation function is located in the class called RatMath.

Comment: if the operator is for `RatNum`, why is it a friend of `RatMath`?

Comment: Ahh, this is where the problem lies. I was treating it like a normal function, didn't realize it had to be in the object class. The const declaration isn't needed so far but I will look it up for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your friend declaration of

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &output, const RatNum &resultObj);
```

should be placed in the (header of) RatNum class, not in the (header of) RatMath Class.

Comment: This is where the problem was, the overload was not in the object class at all. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your function has the wrong types:

`friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &output, RatNum &resultObj);`

should be:

`friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &output, **const** RatNum &resultObj);`

Comment: Although it should be const, *assuming the provided code sample is correct*, that's not the cause of the error.

Comment: Didn't work: "The object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function 'RatNum::getTopNum' object is: const RatNum".

Comment: @AngelaKay Then your `getTopNum` function needs to be const.

Comment: Oh it's so simple. @AngelaKay - You must put the function `ostream& operator<<(ostream &output, RatNum &resultNum)` in the .h file (and mark it inline). Also, you _should_ add const to both the friend declaration and the actual function.